# What is the maximum connection we can make to mqtt through websockets?

Tags: browser, websocket, mosquitto

I am using mosquitto(v-1.5.8) as my broker . I want to connect the broker from browser so I'm using mqtt through websockets. What is the configuration do I include in mosquitto.conf file to get maximum connection or unlimited connection

Comment: What have you already tried, what problems are you hitting?

Comment: I have set the param max_connections to -1 as it denotes unlimited connections. I want to know how many clients are able to connect to broker parallelly .

Comment: You still haven't explained what problems you are seeing.

Answer (score 0):

In `mosquitto.conf`, there is a parameter named `max_connections`, its defualt value is set to -1, which means **unlimited connections**. However this is practically impossible, the maximum number of concurrent connections on MQTT broker should depend on the underlying operating system environment.

For example in Linux/Ubuntu users, maximum number of concurrent connections is determined by number of open files, you can check this by the command `ulimit -a` to list all the limits, see the "open files" part, the value is usually around 1024.

Comment: How "open files" is related to number of connection to  broker ?

Comment: Because everything is a file in Unix, event sockets.